# How to copy two .csv files in one file adjacent to each other in matlab?

Tags: matlab

ex:If I have a file A.csv
[1 2 3
                           4 5 6
                           8 9 7]
and              B.csv
[10 11 12
                        15 16 18
                        19 20 21]
into one file c.csv as
[1 2 3 10 11 12
                        4 5 6 15 16 18
                        8 9 7 19 20 21]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Read this two files by csvread function (documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)

then if your matrices looks like:

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6;8,9,7];
B = [10,11,12;15,16,18;19,20,21];
```

concatenate them:

```
C = [A B];
```

and use csvwrite (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)

```
csvwrite('c.csv',C)
```